# Large Decimal Value to Binary in Arduino

Tags: arduino

I am trying to get the following decimal value

51043465443420856213 to binary in Arduino.

The result should be this.

```
10 1100 0100 0101 1110 1101 0001 0110 0001 1000 0100 0000 0110 1101 1111 1001 0101
```

Comment: Do you want it in a string so you can iterate on the 1's and 0's? Binary is just a base, so technically the number is already equivalent to that in binary.

Comment: The result is a 66 bit binary number.  What is being sought: the _text_ "10 1100 0100 ... 1001 0101" or some number with the value of  `10 1100 0100 ... 1001 0101 base 2`?

Answer (score 1):

Below is a code template to get you going as I did not want to give all the fun away.

```
void print_bin(char *s) {
  // Keep track of carry from previous digit - what should this be initialized to?
  int carry = ...;

  // Divide the "number string" by 2, one digit/character at a time 
  // for each array element in `s` starting with the first character 
  for (... ; ... ; ...) {
    // Extract the string element (character), covert to a decimal digit & add 10x carry
    int digit = ... 
    // Divide digit by 2 and then save as a character
    array element = ...
    // Mod the digit by 2 as the new carry
    carry = ...
  }
  // If first digit is a `0`, then move `s` to the next position.
  if (*s == '0') {
    ...
  }

  // If `s` is not at the end, recursively call this routine on s
  if (...) {
    print_bin(s);
  }

  // Since the more significant digits have been printed, now print
  // this digit (which is "mod 2" of the original "number string") as a character
  fputc('0' + carry, stdout);
}

int main(void) {
  char s[] = "51043465443420856213";
  print_bin(s);
}
```

Result

```
101100010001011110110100010110000110000100000001101101111110010101
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your value is not stored as a c program unsigned long long because it is bigger than 64 bits. Arduino has python. Here is a python function that does what you want. The example is using 80 bits. You can add spaces if you really want them.

```
def int2bin(n, count=24):
    """returns the binary of integer n, using count number of digits"""
    return "".join([str((n >> y) & 1) for y in range(count-1, -1, -1)])

print int2bin(51043465443420856213, 80)
```

Output:
00000000000000101100010001011110110100010110000110000100000001101101111110010101